# Is induction a metalogical concept?

Tags: logic, induction, definition, metalogic

Concepts like induction... are these metalogical concepts? Axioms? Within-logic?

For example proving the [deduction theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Deduction_Theorem) often resorts to principles of induction but I don't see where this "fits" within a system of logic. Like the whole idea of case $P(0)$ being true and case $P(k) \to P(k+1)$ being true implies $P(n)$ is true for all $n$... says who? I'm not saying I am disagreeing with induction, I'm just curious how we "know" it's true and where it actually fits in with our rigorously-defined systems of logic.

Is induction something you can "derive" from the rules of logic or is it something we assume is true on a metalogical level? Where does it fit exactly?

Comment: The Deduction Theorem is a *metalogical* result: it is not a formula of the propositional calculus but a result **about** propositional calculus.

Comment: Thus, the proof of DT is "produced" in the meta-theory and the resources used in the proof, like induction on the lenght of *derivations*, are metalogical resources.

Comment: Induction is formalized in e.g. [first-order theory of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Would the set theory used in the proof of the deduction theorem also be considered metalogical resources?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So the deduction theorem for propositional logic relies on a principle defined in first-order logic?

Comment: Metalogic is "usual" informal mathematics: it uses numbers, sets, trees and so on. If we want to formalize it we have to use a (quite weak) set theory. If so, set theory is able to "reproduce" natural numbers (as sets) and prove Peano's axioms, induction included (they are theorems of set theory).

Comment: "the deduction theorem for propositional logic relies on a principle defined in first-order logic?" Not exactly: **formalized** in first order arithmetic. [Induction has been used in mathematics at least from Fermat](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1080417/why-is-mathematical-induction-called-mathematical).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So any reasoning, logic, set theory, principles like induction, etc, used on a metalogical level aren't "circular" in that they're meant to be interpreted informally?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA not sure I understand. What's the difference between formalize and define?